# Diameter of a circle in taxicab metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to determine the diameter of the circle $C=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ in the taxicab metric. I know I need to compute $\sup\{|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|\}$ with $x_1^2+x_2^2\leq 1$ and $y_1^2+y_2^2\leq 1$ and my intuition says the supremum is $2\sqrt{2}$ but I don't know how to bound it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use [Cauchy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_-_n-dimensional_Euclidean_space) $|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|\leq ((x_1-y_2)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2)^{1/2}(1+1)^{1/2}\leq 2\sqrt{2}$. The example that you have in mind shows that this upper bound is attained.

Comment: Ok, I start to see it @user85667. The only thing I don't see is how the $2$ appears. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: The $2$ comes from $((x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2)^{1/2}\leq 2$. This is because the left is the Euclidean distance between two points, that the largest it can be is the usual diameter of the unit circle, which is $2$.